# How can I create a column containing the maximum across columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have a table CHA with many columns. There are two sets of 5 columns containing numeric data. I am looking to aggregate this data.

Select for the table below:

```
SELECT        Project_Num, Project_Title_Full, PTL, LOB, PL, JobTitle, [Function], MGR, MonthNum, 
              DMD1, DMD0, DMD2, DMD3, DMD4, DRC1, DRC0, DRC2, DRC3, DRC4, CHG0
FROM            Reporter.CHA
```

I am looking to add some aggregate functions DMD_Min, DMD_Max, etc.

I have the following syntax for the new value, but I keep getting an error.

```
(SELECT MIN(MIN_DMD) FROM (VALUES (DMD0), (DMD1), (DMD2), (DMD3), (DMD4)) AS value(MIN_DMD)) AS MIN_DMD
```

Can anyone proved a better method for finding the row by row aggregate across columns?

Edit:

The error I am seeing in SQL server is:

> Error in FROM clause: near 'Values'
>
> Error in FROM clause: near ')'
>
> Unable to parse query text.

This happens when I try to update the query from the select statement above to add in the DMD_MIN column as below:

```
SELECT        Project_Num, Project_Title_Full, PTL, LOB, PL, 
JobTitle, [Function], MGR, MonthNum, DMD1, DMD0, DMD2, DMD3, DMD4, 
DRC1, DRC0, DRC2, DRC3, DRC4, CHG0, 
(SELECT MIN(MIN_DMD) FROM (VALUES 
(DMD0), (DMD1), (DMD2), (DMD3), (DMD4)) AS value(MIN_DMD)) AS MIN_DMD
FROM            Reporter.Compare_HA_Unpivot
```

Comment: Normalise your design, and then you can just do `MIN(DMD)`, or perhaps `MIN(CASE WHEN ValType = 'DMD' THEN Val END)` (depends on your actual data requirements). The reason you have the "jump through hoops" to get the `MIN` of your columns is because of your design.

Comment: `LEAST` and `GREATEST` are available in Azure SQL Database but not on premise yet. Presumably will be included in 2022

Comment: "I keep getting an error" - what exact complete syntax are you using and what error? The code you posted works fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dd56c31e6e6741343533af7f4c02743d

Comment: Edited original post to clarify type of error seen.  I believe I have to be entering some syntax wrong, but can't find it.

Comment: What is `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 12.0.1601.5 (X64)

Comment: What compatibility level is the database set to?

Comment: Compatibility is 130, which is in line with it being SQL Server 2016 I believe

Answer (score 0):

To Larnu's point, your table design is bad and it's leading you to write painful tedious sql statements. Instead consider as a half-way between complete-redesign and tedious-sql something like:

```
SELECT Project_Num, JobTitle, [Function], DMDtype, Min(DMD), Max(DMD)
FROM
    (
        SELECT Project_Num, JobTitle, [Function], 'DMD0' as DMDType, DMD0 FROM Reporter.Cha
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Project_Num, JobTitle, [Function], 'DMD1', DMD1 FROM Reporter.Cha
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Project_Num, JobTitle, [Function], 'DMD2', DMD2 FROM Reporter.Cha
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Project_Num, JobTitle, [Function], 'DMD3', DMD3 FROM Reporter.Cha
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Project_Num, JobTitle, [Function], 'DMD4', DMD5 FROM Reporter.Cha
) sub
GROUP BY Project_Num, JobTitle, [Function], DMDtype;
```

If you want the min and max across all DMD columns, then just remove `dmdtype` from your GROUP BY and SELECT. Ultimately, consider changing your table to look the resultset from that UNION subquery.

Comment: This will scan the table 5 times and is unnecessary. The syntax they have in their Q to select the min from the table value constructor should work

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to offer a solution that masks the bad data design that @Larnu points out, but you could also create a user-defined function that would simplify your query.

```
create function udfBiggestOfFive 
(
     @arg1 as float = null
    ,@arg2 as float = null
    ,@arg3 as float = null
    ,@arg4 as float = null
    ,@arg5 as float = null
)
returns float
as
begin
    
    declare @result as float
    
    set @result = @arg1

    if @result < @arg2 set @result = @arg2
    if @result < @arg3 set @result = @arg3
    if @result < @arg4 set @result = @arg4
    if @result < @arg5 set @result = @arg5

    return @result
end
```

Then your query could be as simple as:

```
select        
    Project_Num, Project_Title_Full, PTL, LOB, PL, JobTitle, [Function], MGR, MonthNum, 
    dbo.BiggestOfFive(DMD1, DMD0, DMD2, DMD3, DMD4) as LargestDmd,
    dbo.BiggestOfFive(DRC1, DRC0, DRC2, DRC3, DRC4) as LargestDrc,
    CHG0
from Reporter.CHA
```

You would create another function for smallest-of-five, if that's what you're interested in (your question kinda jumps around on that) and you'd also want to use Coalesce judiciously if you're not sure there will always be values instead of nulls. But hopefully you get the point.

But... rethink your data design - normalize it. You'll be glad you did. Even this function is a bit silly in its rigid design.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the answer, just need to put your query into an APPLY clause. APPLY will unpivot the data into 1 column, then you can run aggregates like MIN()/MAX() across all 5 data points.

### Unpivot with APPLY then Aggregate

```
SELECT B.MIN_DMD
    ,B.MAX_DMD
    ,A.*
FROM Reporter.CHA AS A
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT MIN_DMD = MIN(DMD) 
                ,MAX_DMD = MAX(DMD)
        FROM (VALUES (DMD0), (DMD1), (DMD2), (DMD3), (DMD4)
        ) AS DTA(DMD)
    ) AS B
```

Alternatively, if you need to know which DMD column contains the highest value, you can use TOP (1) to calculate something like MIN()

### TOP (1) from Unpivot with APPLY

```
SELECT B.DMD_ID
    ,B.DMD_VAL
    ,A.*
FROM Reporter.CHA AS A
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1) *
        FROM (
            VALUES (0,DMD0), (1,DMD1), (2,DMD2), (3,DMD3), (4,DMD4)
        ) AS DTA(DMD_ID,DMD_VAL)
        ORDER BY DMD_VAL
    ) AS B
```